# link_to_unless do

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, link-to

Here's a typical `link_to_unless`:

```
<%= link_to_unless(@current_user.nil?, "Reply", { :action => "reply" }) %>
```

How can I do the same thing with a block?

```
# non-functional
<%= link_to_unless(@current_user.nil?, ..., { :action => "reply" }) do %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

`link_to_unless` already accepts a block. You need to pass a block argument for to access the link title parameter, though.

```
link_to_unless(@current_user.nil?, "Name", { :action => "reply" }) do |name|
  link_to name, some_path
```

At this point though you have to ask yourself if it's just easier to do and if/else statement.

Answer (score 0):

put this in a helper

```
def link_to_unless_with_block condition, uri, &block
   link_to_unless condition, capture(&block), uri
end
```

should work.. though not tested